# What has really happened when Windows says "X has stopped working"?

Tags: windows-7

I have had an online backup service (which I cannot recommend) and purchased a Seagate drive and downloaded Seagate Dashboard to do job instead.  After two days of making my initial backup, and still working on it, I get the typical windows message that said something like "Dashboard has stopped working", and giving me options for either closing the program or having (someone?) search for a solution and THEN close the program.  I voted to just close it, because I don't trust Windows to search that sort of thing for me.

The thing is, the Dashboard program wasn't stopped.  It continues to chew up CPU and wireless connection speed and so forth just like it has for the last two days, and continues to increase the "percentage complete" number at the same glacial pace (I'm not complaining, I know this takes a long time -- just saying it didn't change its behavior).

But clearly the message didn't mean what I thought it meant -- that it had detected that this process had somehow ended.  So what does it mean?  I'm a programmer by trade, so I can stand a reasonable amount of technical explanation...

Comment: Since you are a programmer, perhaps this is the best answer for you: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304991 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx in short, it appears to be determined by whether the Process.MainWindowHandle responds to WaitForInputIdle within a reasonable period of time. if the UI is on a thread that is deadlocked, or on an infinite loop, it will fail to hit input idle state.

Comment: so, a poorly written program, that uses a single thread for UI and work, which does not pause its work periodically to respond to UI events like Draw(), will appear to be not responding. Basically anytime the UI thread fails to get execution time for any period of time, windows will report it as not responding.

Comment: Excellent answer; If you will copy these things to an answer, I will accept it as one.  So that explains why Win7 can report it as "stopped" even though it really hasn't, and I can attest to just how poorly its UI responds.  Seagate has a service, I would think its backup work would have to be done there, and I have NO idea what "work" it could be doing while waiting for UI input.  So that's a new mystery, though not one I expect anyone outside of that program's author(s) to know about.  Thanks.

Comment: @rcook: I think you mean "Stopped Responding" -- "Stopped Working" means the program has crashed.

Comment: Stopped working, as a windows dialog, is an extension of the not responding behavior, and indicates that one of the threads or child-processes has encountered an unhandled exception, while performing an asynchronous operation, such that the UI form does not know that it will never receive a callback, and continuously spins waiting for the asynch op to complete. Windows must be the arbiter and display the message in this case, because the UI thread cannot. There are cases where the program is gunning away, and ceases responding, but that will not cause a stopped working dialog.

Comment: @jdigital Thanks, that is likely the message I saw -- I hadn't thought of posting here before I closed it, so I had not written it down and had no way to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Vista and newer implement checks for [the responsiveness of UI based applications](http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/newsroom/windows/factsheets/WindowsVistaFS.mspx) by default.

This may lead an application to be labeled as "Not responding" either while it is in the foreground (taskbar), or when its window takes focus (dialog).

When the application is not responding, and the OS can infer that the failure is related to an exception in a child module, of which the application itself is unaware, windows knows the application cannot display its own error message, write to the system eventlog, and create a crash report, windows displays a dialog indicating that the process has "Stopped Working". This is slightly different than an application crash, because the stack of the main executable has not itself crashed; it is however generally waiting for a response from the child module that will never come. The event log will often contain information about the child's exception.

An app is considered non-responsive when the Windows API cannot detect that the UI window has entered into a where the user can manipulate it in some time. In C#, you can [query the windows status to check its responsiveness](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304991) with the call `Process.Responding()`. This method returns false, (or raise an exception if the [MainWindowHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not exist) or true if the window is in an Idle status, and is awaiting input.

There are cases where a **non-responsive** program is in actually doing a lot of work, exactly as its supposed to, so an unresponsive message is not always indicative of a failure (just kinda bad code). The desktop window may eventually become responsive. A **"Stopped Working"** dialog however usually does indicate a permanent failure, and the application will need to be aborted. This is not 100% true all the time, but more often than not, it is the case.

The nature of these messages and their associated problems is inseparable from the programming techniques used in performing work, and integrating with external components and services like external APIs. Microsoft has released some good information on what to do and not do, to develop a [responsive UI design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Poor threading strategies, synchronous and asynchronous access to external components, and resource contention (locks/deadlocks) are the common causes.

For end users suffering from issues with applications that "Stopped Working" Microsoft recommends an extensive troubleshooting path, found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2694911 The video card driver is often responsible for issues with the Draw() loop, and can thus cause non-responsiveness, as are the system APIs. verifying the driver installation and that the OS itself is integral (with SFC.exe) are worthwhile steps to determine that the application integrates with your system tightly, as expected. Hardware like the Video Card and RAM must be working correctly as well.

I hope that helps

Comment: That helps.  I'll have to come back and analyze the difference between this answer and the typical MS article(s) on the same subject; on first read they appear to have about the same density of technical knowledge, but yours is much more readable and informative and theirs just leave me feeling like I've been given data, not information.  Thanks again.